# Cannot Find Symbol Error on Android Studio

Tags: android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
      return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  /**
   * Increase the score for Team A by 1 point.
   */
  public void addOneForTeamA(View v) {
    displayForTeamA(1);
  }

  /**
   * Increase the score for Team A by 2 points.
   */
  public void addTwoForTeamA(View v) {
    displayForTeamA(2);
  }

  /**
   * Increase the score for Team A by 3 points.
   */
  public void addThreeForTeamA(View v) {
    displayForTeamA(3);
  }

  /**
   * Displays the given score for Team A.
   */
  public void displayForTeamA(int score) {
    TextView scoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.team_a_score);
    scoreView.setText(String.valueOf(score));
  }
}
```

these are the two errors that i am  getting please help me solve them.
these lines of code are actualyy copied fromgithub udacity android for beginer code

> Error:(21, 36) error: cannot find symbol variable menu
>   Error:(33, 23) error: cannot find symbol variable action_settings

Comment: Do you have any item in res/menu/menu_main.xml with ID == action_settings?

Comment: nope actually i have done a very similar code before and it worked just fine  i dont know why am i geting this  now

Comment: This error is happening because there are no views (or menu items) with ID == action_settings. Check res/menu/menu_main.xml and get the proper ID (or share file res/menu/menu_main.xml)

Comment: i ll just reask the question with xml code and the correct code too please see if uou figure out the solution to this app

Comment: thank you all of you for helping.@Guilherme P thank you your advise worked.just deleted those things

Answer (score 0):

It means you are missing the variables with id menu and action_settings in your resources/menu folder.

Answer (score 0):

You are having two errors:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
```

and here

```
if (id == R.id.action_settings)
```

Basically, Android Studio is not generating R.menu items... I believe then, there's no file inside `/res/menu/` (and according to your code, it should exist a `/res/menu/menu_main.xml` file.

So, I see two possibilities:

**Remove menu code**

Since you don't have `/res/menu/menu_main.xml` file, it seems that you are not using a Menu... So, remove `public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` and `public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)` methods from your MainActivity.java

**Create menu file**

If you want to use a Menu, you must create a file under /res/menu/menu_main.xml and configure it properly... That file should have at least one item with ID `android:id="@+id/action_settings"`